# How to plot two columns based histograms with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to plot a two column table (two variables) in a single histogram. Is that possible ? what's a good approach is this case ? and what are the alternatives if histograms are not recommended ?

Example :

[image: The data to plot as a histogram in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a combination chart of column and line:

[image]